# Why does wp_insert_attachment not working on PHP 8?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, php-8

I am trying to upload a file from an external URL to wordpress media library, within my custom wordpress plugin.

This is currently the code I am using:

```
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');


function rudr_upload_file_by_url( $image_url ) {

    // it allows us to use download_url() and wp_handle_sideload() functions
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    // download to temp dir
    $temp_file = download_url( $image_url );

    if( is_wp_error( $temp_file ) ) {
        return false;
    }


    // move the temp file into the uploads directory
    $file = array(
        'name'     => basename( $image_url ),
        'type'     => mime_content_type( $temp_file ),
        'tmp_name' => $temp_file,
        'size'     => filesize( $temp_file ),
    );
    $sideload = wp_handle_sideload(
        $file,
        array(
            'test_form'   => false // no needs to check 'action' parameter
        )
    );

    if( ! empty( $sideload[ 'error' ] ) ) {
        // you may return error message if you want
        return false;
    }


    // it is time to add our uploaded image into WordPress media library
    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment(
        array(
            'guid'           => $sideload[ 'url' ],
            'post_mime_type' => $sideload[ 'type' ],
            'post_title'     => basename( $sideload[ 'file' ] ),
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        ),
        $sideload[ 'file' ]
    );

    if( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) || ! $attachment_id ) {
    // => Error is happening within here $attachment_id is 0
        return false;
    }

    // update medatata, regenerate image sizes
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    wp_update_attachment_metadata(
        $attachment_id,
        wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $sideload[ 'file' ] )
    );

    return $attachment_id;

}



$test_url = 'https://www.mundo-flamenco.com/typo3temp/GB/a5ddd34bdf.png'; 

$res = rudr_upload_file_by_url($test_url); 

echo $res; 

?>
```

Unfortunately it is not working, $res = false, and I also don't really know how I can debug it further.

I have set WP_DEBUG to TRUE but it is not showing anything.

Update: I have tried on a different install with PHP 7 where it is working but unfortunately doesn't seem to work with PHP 8

I tested on the same server with PHP version 7.4 (which does work fine), and PHP 8.1 (which doesn't). I would still like to find a possible solution for PHP 8 though if anyone knows.

Comment: I'm not sure your problem, but you have two `return false;` statements, and I would recommend finding out which one is hitting. You can just add a `die('first');` and `die('second');` to help with this

Comment: Thanks it is the second one. I have added a comment.

Comment: `wp_insert_attachment` returns a `WP_Error` on failure, you should dump that out to see the message

Comment: Thanks again, but it is not showing an error it is only returning 0

Comment: Per the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_attachment/), looks like you also need to pass `true` as the fourth parameter for it to return the error message

Comment: Yes thanks for the hint, I have also tried that, but still the return value was just 0

Comment: I think it has something to do with PHP versions, I will check that and update as soon as I know

Comment: Yh so I tested on the same server with PHP version 7.4 (which does work fine), and PHP 8.1 (which doesn't). I would still like to find a possible solution for PHP 8 though if anyone knows.

Comment: Make sure that full PHP error reporting is turned on, and that you are checking other potential logs on your server